# main function keeps repeating itself for no reason

Tags: pic18

Hi guys please help me out...i dont know why the void main() function keep on repeating itself without any while loop. Onto the LCD first "IN PROGRESS"(status1) is displayed and then "IDLE MODE"(status2) then after 500ms delay "IN PROGRESS"(status1) then "IDLE MODE"(status2) keeps repeating and it never displays "SPI MODE(status3). I don't know whats happening may be the microcontroller resets itself. Any help would be appreciated. I am using MPLAB IDEv8.92 with C18 compiler.Thanks in advance.

```
#include <p18f4550.h>
#pragma config WDT = OFF
#define SCK LATBbits.LATB1              //Pin34 as Output
#define SDA PORTBbits.RB0               //Pin33 as Input
#define CS LATCbits.LATC2               //Pin17 as Output
#define SDO LATCbits.LATC7              //Pin26 as Output
#define LD LATD                         
#define RS LATEbits.LATE1
#define E LATEbits.LATE2
void cmdwrite(unsigned char);
void datawrite(unsigned char);
void strdis(unsigned char *str);
void initialize_SDC(void);
void ms_delay(void);
void msd(void);
void dis2digit(unsigned int var3);
void main()
    {
        unsigned char status1[20]="IN PROGRESS";
            SSPSTATbits.SMP=1;
            SSPSTATbits.CKE=0;
            SSPCON1=0x22;
            SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 1;
            ms_delay();ms_delay();
            TRISBbits.TRISB1=0;                     //Pin34(SCK) as Output
            TRISBbits.TRISB0=1;                     //Pin33(SDA) as Input
            TRISCbits.TRISC2=0;                     //Pin17(CS) as Output
            TRISCbits.TRISC7=0;                     //Pin26(SDO) as Output
            TRISD=0;
            ADCON1=0x0F;
            TRISE=0;
            E=0;
            CS=1;
            cmdwrite(0x38);
            cmdwrite(0x38);
            cmdwrite(0x38);
            cmdwrite(0x0C);
            cmdwrite(0x82);
            strdis(status1);        //Displays IN PROGRESS
            initialize_SDC();
    }
void initialize_SDC(void)
    {
        unsigned char status2[20]="IDLE MODE";
        unsigned char status3[20]="SPI MODE";
        unsigned char i=0,j=0,r1=0xFF,high=0xFF,ar1=0xFF,spi_r1=0xFF;
        unsigned char cmd0[6]={0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x95};      // CMD0
        unsigned char cmd1[6]={0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x95};
        unsigned char cmd55[6]={0x77,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01};
        unsigned char acmd41[6]={0x69,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01};
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                CS=1;
                SDO=high;       //Warming Up Card by sending 80 Clock Pulses
            }
            CS=0;
        if(r1==0xFF)
        {   
            for(j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                SDO=cmd0[j];        // Sending CMD0
            }
                SDO=high;
                r1=SDA;             //Keep Sending Dummy Bytes until 0x01 is received
            CS=1;
            if(r1==0x01)
            {
            cmdwrite(0x01);
            cmdwrite(0x83);
            strdis(status2);        //Displays IDLE MODE if the response is valid
            msd();msd();
            }
        }   

        CS=1;
        CS=0;
        while(ar1==0xFF)
        {
        SDO=high;
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                SDO=cmd1[j];        // Sending CMD0
            }
                SDO=high;
                ar1=SDA;                //Keep Sending Dummy Bytes until 0x01 is received
                CS=1;
            if(ar1==0x00)
            {
            cmdwrite(0x01);
            cmdwrite(0x83);
            strdis(status3);        //Displays IDLE MODE if the response is valid
            msd();msd();
            }
        }
        /*for(i=0;i<6;i++)  
        {
            SDO=cmd55[i];           //CMD55
        }
        SDO=high;                   //Send dummy byte
        ar1=SDA;                    //Get Response for CMD55
            if(ar1=0x00)            //Check if Response(R1) is valid
            {
                CS=1;
                CS=0;
                for(i=0;i<6;i++)
                {
                    SDO=acmd41[i];      //ACMD41
                }
            SDO=high;                   //Send dummy byte
            spi_r1=SDA;                 //Get Response for ACMD41
            if(spi_r1==0x00)            //Check if Response(R1) is valid
            {
                cmdwrite(0x01);
                cmdwrite(0x88);
                strdis(status3);        //Displays SPI MODE if the response is valid
                msd();msd();
            }
            CS=1;
            }*/
    }
void cmdwrite(unsigned char var1)
{
LD=var1;
RS=0;
/*RW is grounded */
E=1;
ms_delay();
E=0;
}
void datawrite(unsigned char var2)
{
LD=var2;
RS=1;
/*RW is grounded */
E=1;
ms_delay();
E=0;
}
void strdis(unsigned char *str)
{
        while(*str!='\0')
        {
        datawrite(*str);
        str++;
        }
}
void dis2digit(unsigned int var3)
{
     unsigned int hp,up,tp,x;
     x=var3/10;
     hp=x/10;
     tp=x%10;
     up=var3%10;
     datawrite(hp+48);
     datawrite(tp+48);
     datawrite(up+48);
}
void ms_delay(void)
{
T1CON = 0x30;
TMR1H=0xC2;
TMR1L=0xF7;
T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;
while(PIR1bits.TMR1IF==0);
T1CONbits.TMR1ON=0;
PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;
}
void msd(void)
{
T1CON = 0x30;
TMR1H=0x67;
TMR1L=0x6A;
T1CONbits.TMR1ON=1;
while(PIR1bits.TMR1IF==0);
T1CONbits.TMR1ON=0;
PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your questions:

1) You should always have a "super-loop" or infinite loop in your embedded code before the end of the main function. I suspect the reason your microcontroller is "resetting" is because you don't have such a loop before the end of your main, and the program returns to the first instruction line. Insert this code before the end of your main:

```
 while(1) {

 }
```

2) I suspect the reason you never display SPI MODE(status 3) is because you are never entering the "if" statement:

```
if(ar1 == 0x00)
```

in your previous statement where you display SPI MODE(status 2), this "if" statement is

```
if(r1 == 0x01).
```

Try changing the statement to:

```
if(ar1 == 0x01)
```

Even your comments suggest that you are looping until the value 0x01 is achieved. Hopefully this works for you!